# Meaning of "home" in "If every recovery has a home, this is the one for me"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not sure if I understand the word *home* in this sentence:

> If every recovery has a home, this is the one for me.

What's the meaning of *home* here? Is it the same as *house*?

Comment: Hello, Denise. Some more context is necessary for an answer not too dependent on guesswork. The sense in which 'recovery' is being used here is perhaps key.

Comment: The author is talking about his drug addiction. But my doubt is: is it a kind of idiom: "if..... has a home, this is the one for me"? Is it used in other contexts? Or it is a metaphor created by the author?

Comment: "Every recovery has a home" might be an addiction recovery slogan or proverb, similar to "you are as sick as your secrets" or "one day at a time".

Comment: Sorry, I meant a few more sentences from the original. As it stands, the meaning of 'recovery' in the count sense used here, and the status of 'home', is unclear. One could guess at 'If a homely environment is necessary for any person to be able to come off drugs, I can't imagine a better setting than this one.'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the context is unknown, maybe these suggestions will help:

If the context is for drug addiction, I believe this phrase is a metaphor for someone finding the best method for rehabilitation.

If the context is for recovering from one or more unfortunate events to one's life, it is likely a metaphor for finding a path or work that brings good.